# cocos 2d-x automation testing tool for mobile games

Tags: automation, cocos2d-x, appium

Is there any tool or methods to do automation testing for games developed in cocos2d-x?
FYI: Appium and other tools try to find Android and IOS elements, I don't use them in the games.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use Image Recognition for Mobile App Game Testing, Appium too supports Image recognition.

---

You can use [applitools](https://applitools.com/) for doing automatic image comparison with Appium. In fact Applitools automates not only the capturing of the screenshot, but also it's validation, and has sophisticated algorithms to avoid false failures of the image comparison. Applitools' Selenium SDK works out of the box with Appium as well as with any other WebDriver implementation, and is cross-platform and cross-device. Applitools have a free registration plan, and the SDKs are open source and available on GitHub.

---

For More Information Use below links
[Image Recognition Part 1](http://testdroid.com/news/how-to-use-image-recognition-for-mobile-app-and-game-testing)
and [Image Recognition Part 2](http://testdroid.com/tech/mobile-game-testing-part-2-ui-and-functionality-image-recognition) also take a look at [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)